# JQuery string not parsing correctly in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, string, serialization

In a previous post, I asked about how to deserialize a JQuery string, and was told to use parse_str().  However, I didn't post my code until later.  So, here is my JQuery string:

```
age_gender=1&age_gender=2&age_gender=3&age_gender=4&age_gender=5&age_gender=6
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['age_gender'])) { 
     $formSerialized = $_POST['age_gender'];
     $formData = array();
     parse_str($formSerialized, $formData);
     addRow($formData, $link); 
}

function addRow($dataArray, $link) {
     $age_group = $dataArray[0];
     $populations = array(intval($dataArray[1]) + intval($dataArray[2]), intval($dataArray[1]), intval($dataArray[2]));
     $percents = array(doubleval($dataArray[3]) + doubleval($dataArray[4]), doubleval($dataArray[3]), doubleval($dataArray[4]));
     $m_per_100_f = doubleval($dataArray[6]);
     $query = "INSERT INTO national_age_gender_demographics (age_group, both_pop, male_pop, female_pop, both_percent, male_percent, female_percent, males_per_100_females)
     VALUES ('$age_group','$populations[0]','$populations[1]','$populations[2]','$percents[0]','$percents[1]','$percents[2]','$m_per_100_f')";
     $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

     if(!$result)  die( "Query: " . $query . "\nError:" . mysql_error() );
}
```

For some reason, I am getting a blank string for $age_group, and 0's for all other values. Could anyone help me here?

Comment: how many values age_gender recived?

Comment: why same name for all parameters

Comment: I was about to ask the same, age_gender is being overrriden so you just recive one value.

Comment: PHP expects `age_gender` to be `age_gender[]`, as it's an array.

Comment: So, do I replace both instances of `age_gender` with `age_gender[]`?

Comment: All 6 instances should be replaced. Then you don't need to call `parse_str()`, the parsing is done automatically by PHP when it fills in `$_POST`.

Comment: You need to change the fields on your form to be `name="age_gender[]"` so when jquery serializes the form it makes the serialized string `age_gender[]=1&age_gender[]=2...etc`

Comment: in you form replace all `name="age_gender"` with `name="age_gender[]"`.. that is, if you've a form with some element with `name="age_gender"` at first place. And then in your PHP, just do `$formData = $_POST['age_gender']`

Comment: Tried this, still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass the data like this instead:

```
age_gender[]=1&age_gender[]=2&age_gender[]=3&age_gender[]=4&age_gender[]=5&age_gender[]=6
```

note the `'[]'` after the name, if they come from html input you would just have to name your html input `age_gender[]`.
Then you function addRow should look like:

```
    function addRow($dataArray, $link) {
     $dataArray = $dataArray['age_gender'];//Added this line
     $age_group = $dataArray[0];
     $populations = array(intval($dataArray[1]) + intval($dataArray[2]), intval($dataArray[1]), intval($dataArray[2]));
     $percents = array(doubleval($dataArray[3]) + doubleval($dataArray[4]), doubleval($dataArray[3]), doubleval($dataArray[4]));
     $m_per_100_f = doubleval($dataArray[6]);
     $query = "INSERT INTO national_age_gender_demographics (age_group, both_pop, male_pop, female_pop, both_percent, male_percent, female_percent, males_per_100_females)
     VALUES ('$age_group','$populations[0]','$populations[1]','$populations[2]','$percents[0]','$percents[1]','$percents[2]','$m_per_100_f')";
     $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

     if(!$result)  die( "Query: " . $query . "\nError:" . mysql_error() );
}
```

Comment: Okay, looks like that JQuery is giving this string:

`age_gender%5B%5D=1&age_gender%5B%5D=2&age_gender%5B%5D=3&age_gender%5B%5D=4&age_gender%5B%5D=5&age_gender%5B%5D=6 `

Why are my square brackets being replaced by escape codes?

Comment: Oh, got it, I had to keep my previous code to deserialize the JQuery string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try encoding with Json, this is a good solution

$.stringfy(your_var);

and to read with php use json_decode